# Saving data in OL3

Tags: geojson, openlayers

I have a small app where I would like to be able to digitize new features and save them for use outside the app.

I am using geojson as I don't have a geoserver
I have managed to create a button that then allows features to be drawn into the json layer but I can't figure out how to save the changes.

I found this info

reading geojson:

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
```

writing geojson:

```
var json= new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatures(features);
```

I then need to save the file back to the server using ajax ????? what how ?